# Android calendar doesn't show add event activity

Tags: android, calendar

I'm using this code to add a new event to the Calendar

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
   intent.setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI);
   intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, "Dummy Title");
```

It works fine but if after adding the event if I wouldn't close the Calendar app i.e. open apps launch history and go back to my app then try to add a new event it just resumes the Calendar app. So it won't start the add event activity and just opens events list in the calendar. I've tested this on Nexus 6 with Android M. Does anyone know to fix the issue?